# 2D nonlinear PDE describing leveling process of fluid

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I already asked a question regarding how to solve a nonlinear pde in mathematica which was answered nicely.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134145/solving-a-non-linear-pde

Actually this was a 1-dimensional form of a general 2D problem that I was trying to solve with matlab, but first I wanted to have a clue about the solution using mathematica. Now I think I have to restrict myself into solving it in mathematica. Here is the 2D form of the problem with its initial and boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = -0.01 \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Big(h^3  \big(\frac{\partial^3h}{\partial x^3}+\frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial x\partial y^2}\big)\Big)+
 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big(h^3 \big(\frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial y^3}+\frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial y\partial x^2}\big)\Big)\bigg)$$
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=0,\ \ \frac{\partial^3h}{\partial x^3}+\frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial x\partial y^2}=0\ \ \text{when}\ \ x=\pm1$$
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=0,\ \ \frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial y^3}+\frac{\partial ^3h}{\partial y\partial x^2}=0\ \ \text{when}\ \ y=\pm1$$
$$h(0,x,y)=1+\cos(\pi x) \cos(\pi y)$$
I tried to do the same as the 1D case, however it gives me an error with the boundary conditions. I tried this:

```
t0 = 6;
BCLx1 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, -1, y];

BCRx1 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, y];

BCLx3 = Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][t, x, -1]+Derivative[0, 1, 2][u][t, -1, y];

BCRx3 = Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][t, x, 1]+Derivative[0, 1, 2][u][t, 1, y];

BCLy1 = Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, -1];

BCRy1 = Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 1];

BCLy3 = Derivative[0, 0, 3][u][t, x, -1]+Derivative[0, 2, 1][u][t, x, -1];

BCRy3 = Derivative[0, 0, 3][u][t, x, 1]+Derivative[0, 2, 1][u][t, x, 1];

sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], 
 t] == -0.0192*
               (D[u[t, x, y]^3*(D[u[t, x, y], {x, 3}] + 
                D[D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}], x]), x] + 
                D[u[t, x, y]^3*(D[u[t, x, y], {y, 3}] + 
                D[D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}], y]), y]), 
          u[0, x, y] == Cos[π y] Cos[π x] + 1,
          BCLx1 == 0, 
          BCRx1 == 0, 
          BCLx3 == 0, 
          BCRx3 == 0, 
          BCLy1 == 0, 
          BCRy1 == 0, 
          BCLy3 == 0, 
          BCRy3 == 0}, 
      u, {t, 0, t0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 100}}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2]; Plot3D[{u[t0, x, y] /. sol}, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It states that the boundary conditions include non-normal derivatives! but they are all meaningful BCs based on the physics of the problem.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your translation for `BCRx3` and `BCLx3` is wrong. Still, `NDSolve` isn't able to handle these b.c.s even after correcting this. Are you sure the b.c.s are correct? What material are you referring to?

Comment: This problem represents the leveling of a liquid film over a flat surface as a function of time. These two papers address this problem in a more general way (which is not the case for me and I have made it simpler without any unrealistic change):

Comment: The problem represents the leveling of a liquid film on a flat surface as a function of time. These two papers address this problem in a general way (which is not the case for me; I have made it simpler without any unrealistic change):
1-Numerical simulation of thin paint film flow, Bruno Figliuzzi eta al, 2012
2-Three-Dimensional Direct Numerical Simulation of Surface-Tension-Gradient Effects on the Leveling of an Evaporating Multicomponent Fluid, M. H. Eres, 1998
Based on the problem, the slope(dh/dx) and the flux (qx =d^3h/dx^3+d^3h/dxdy^2) of the liquid at the boundaries are all zero.

Answer (score 3):

OK, even after the incorrect translation for `BCRx3` and `BCLx3` is amended, `NDSolve` can't handle this kind of boundary conditions, so let's discretize spatial dimensions outside of `NDSolve`, with the help of [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871):

```
t0 = 6;
BCLx1 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, -1, y];
BCRx1 = Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 1, y];
BCLx3 = Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][t, -1, y] + Derivative[0, 1, 2][u][t, -1, y];
BCRx3 = Derivative[0, 3, 0][u][t, 1, y] + Derivative[0, 1, 2][u][t, 1, y];
BCLy1 = Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, -1];
BCRy1 = Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, x, 1];
BCLy3 = Derivative[0, 0, 3][u][t, x, -1] + Derivative[0, 2, 1][u][t, x, -1];
BCRy3 = Derivative[0, 0, 3][u][t, x, 1] + Derivative[0, 2, 1][u][t, x, 1];
eqn = D[u[t, x, y], 
    t] == -0.0192*(D[u[t, x, y]^3*(D[u[t, x, y], {x, 3}] + D[D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}], x]), 
       x] + D[u[t, x, y]^3*(D[u[t, x, y], {y, 3}] + D[D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}], y]), y]);
ic = u[0, x, y] == Cos[π y] Cos[π x] + 1;
bc = {BCLx1 == 0, BCRx1 == 0, BCLx3 == 0, BCRx3 == 0, BCLy1 == 0, BCRy1 == 0, BCLy3 == 0,
    BCRy3 == 0};

xdomain = ydomain = {-1, 1};
xpoints = ypoints = 30;
xgrid = Array[# &, xpoints, xdomain];
ygrid = Array[# &, ypoints, ydomain];
difforder = 4;
var = Outer[u, xgrid, ygrid];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this code piece, 
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoo = pdetoode[u[t, x, y], t, {xgrid, ygrid}, difforder];

del = Delete[#, {{1}, {2}, {-2}, {-1}}] &;
ode = del /@ del@ptoo@eqn;
odeic = del /@ del@ptoo@ic;
odebc = MapAt[del, ptoo@bc, List /@ Range@4];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, var, {t, 0, t0}, 
                      SolveDelayed -> True]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.970609, Null} *)

sol = rebuild[sollst, {xgrid, ygrid}, -1];

Animate[
 Plot3D[sol[x, y, t], {x, xdomain} // Flatten // Evaluate, {y, ydomain} // Flatten // 
   Evaluate, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image]

`SolveDelayed -> True` option is necessary at least for *v10.2*, its color is red, but don't worry.

Comment: I copy and paste  this code with `pdetoode` dosen't work!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk As mentioned above, the definition of `pdetoode` isn't included in this post, please find it in the link at the beginning of the post.

Comment: i'm add a `pdetoode` code.I.have error messages: `\!\({t, 0, 6}[\"ValuesOnGrid\"]\) cannot be used as a variable. `

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Show me a screen shot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ErvYioO`+`http://imgur.com/gOoD7Gn`+`http://imgur.com/LY4gJfd

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk What's the output if you execute `ode[[1, 1]]` now? Is it something like this?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AfZ3B.png

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I didn't got any error. I have uploaded the complete worksheet. check it. https://www.dropbox.com/s/usuvaw8yvwdejzn/questions134290.nb?dl=0

Comment: The only problem I am facing is that `Abort Dynamic Evaluation`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes I have equation like this: i.stack.imgur.com/AfZ3B.png

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I guess it's a backslide of v10.2, what if you add `SolveDelayed->True` to `NDSolveValue`? (`SolveDelayed` will be red, but don't worry. )

Comment: @mmm I've no idea, but I heard more than once that the dynamic  functionality of _Mathematica_  regresses in some aspects since v10. Maybe changing `Animate` to `Manipulate` and taking away `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` will help?

Comment: If I upload  yours *nb file On MMA 11.0 and MMA 10.2 Works. `SolveDelayed->True` helps.Thanks for ALL. :)

Comment: @xzcz I faced the same problem as zhk, `Abort Dynamic Evaluation`, Manipulate also not work. Thank you for any help.

Comment: @S.Cho Which version are you in? Anyway, if you just need a workaround, try e.g. `lst = Table[
   Plot3D[sol[t, x, y], {x, xdomain} // Flatten // Evaluate, {y, ydomain} // Flatten // 
     Evaluate, PlotRange -> {-1, 2}], {t, 0, 1/2, 1/48}]; ListAnimate@lst`

Comment: It's 11.3, Okey I'll try this.

Comment: not working https://i.stack.imgur.com/eke2w.jpg

Comment: @S.Cho …You didn't execute the code before this line. Notice the color of `sol` etc. is blue.

Comment: I did before rerun the file, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG1uH.jpg

Comment: @xzczd Now, It work with this `Animate[Plot3D[
  sol[t, x, y], {x, Min [xdomain], Max[xdomain]} // Flatten // 
   Evaluate, {y, Min [ydomain], Max[ydomain]} // Flatten // Evaluate, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @S.Cho Then the `Animate[…]` in my answer should work, too. You must have done something wrong 20 hours ago.