# using a custom method to discretize functions with 3 variables to be used in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, discretization

I was using the `pdetoode` function that @xzczd made:
[Dynamic Euler–Bernoulli beam equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997)

But it only works for functions with 2 variables, I was wondering if it could be changed to fit functions with 3 variables, and if so, how?

And this is how I try to use it:

```
eqnstest = D[T[x, y, t], y] == 0;
Tpdetood = pdetoode[T[x, y, t], y, gridy, 1];
eqnstest // Tpdetood
```

But this produces a whole list of errors, which I presume is because the method is not suited for it,
I tried to contact the guy himself, but I have not found a way to do it on Stackexchange, and to comment you need 50 reputation to do that on other posts.

EDIT, added the code I am using for the total solution. The problem is that it won't evaluate since everything at the beginning just gives True,  probably a result of "removeredundant" isn't accurate

```
P[x_, y_, t_] = e[x, y, t]/(γ - 1) ; 
e[x_, y_, t_] = (γ - 1) ρ[x, y, t]/(μ mu )kb T[x, y, t]; 
cp = 5/2 kb/(μ mu);
Rgas = 8.3144598;
cv = 5/2 kb/(μ mu) - Rgas;
γ = cp/cv;
g = 28.02*9.81;
μ = 0.6163328197226503`;
mu = 1.66053904*10^-27;
kb = 1.38064852*10^-23;
{grid@x, grid@y} = {Array[12000000/300 # &, 300], 
Array[4000000/100 # &, 100]};

eqns1 = D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], 
t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t] + P[x, y, t], x] - 
D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], y];
eqns2 = D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], 
t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], y] - 
D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t] + P[x, y, t], y] + 
g ρ[x, y, t];
eqns3 = D[ρ[x, y, t], t] == -D[ρ[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t], x] - 
D[ρ[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t], y];
eqns4 = D[e[x, y, t], t] == -D[u[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], x] - 
D[v[x, y, t]*e[x, y, t], y] - 
P[x, y, t]*(D[u[x, y, t], x] - D[v[x, y, t], y]);
bc = {
v[x, 4000000, t] == 0,
v[x, 40000, t] == 0,
(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 40000) == 0,
(D[u[x, y, t], y] /. y -> 4000000) == 0,
ρ[x, 40000, t] == 0.0001999359999999999,
e[x, 40000, t] == 15562.721977320278 (γ - 1),
ρ[x, 4000000, t] == 0.003142381499745774,
e[x, 4000000, t] == 1.66117*10^6 (γ - 1)
};
ics = {v[x, y, 0] == 0, u[x, y, 0] == 0, 
T[x, y, 0] == 5000 + 0.008354149607 y, ρ[x, y, 0] == 
1.42*   10^-7*1.408*10^3 + 7.3561137493644*10^-10 y};
pdenoot1 = 
  pdetoode[{T, ρ, u, v}[x, y, t], t, {grid@x, grid@y}, 
    3, {True, False}];
    pdenoot2 = 
 pdetoode[{ρ, u, v}[x, y, t], t, {grid@x, grid@y}, 
3, {True, False}];
pdenoot3 = 
 pdetoode[{T, ρ, u, v}[x, y, t], t, {grid@x, grid@y}, 
 3, {True, False}];

 removeredundant = #[[5 ;; -5]] &;
del= #[[2 ;; -2, 1 ;; -1]] &;;
 odeq1 = del /@ del@pdenoot1@eqns1;
 odeq2 = del /@ del@pdenoot1@eqns2;
 odeq3 = del /@ del@pdenoot2@eqns3;
 odeq4 = del /@ del@pdenoot3@eqns4;
 odebcs = del /@ del@pdenoot1@bc;
 odeic = pdenoot1@ics;
 sollst = NDSolveValue[{odeq1, odeq2, odeq3, odeq4, odebcs, 
  odeic}, {ρ, T, u, v} /@ grid, {t, 0, 10}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

The following error shows up:

```
NDSolveValue::ndode: The equations {v[12000000,40000][0]==0,v[12000000,80000][0]==0,v[12000000,120000][0]==0,v[12000000,160000][0]==0,v[12000000,200000][0]==0,v[12000000,240000][0]==0,v[12000000,280000][0]==0,v[12000000,320000][0]==0,v[12000000,360000][0]==0,v[12000000,400000][0]==0,v[12000000,440000][0]==0,v[12000000,480000][0]==0,v[12000000,520000][0]==0,v[12000000,560000][0]==0,v[12000000,600000][0]==0,v[12000000,640000][0]==0,<<19>>,v[12000000,1440000][0]==0,v[12000000,1480000][0]==0,v[12000000,1520000][0]==0,v[12000000,1560000][0]==0,v[12000000,1600000][0]==0,v[12000000,1640000][0]==0,v[12000000,1680000][0]==0,v[12000000,1720000][0]==0,v[12000000,1760000][0]==0,v[12000000,1800000][0]==0,v[12000000,1840000][0]==0,v[12000000,1880000][0]==0,v[12000000,1920000][0]==0,v[12000000,1960000][0]==0,v[12000000,2000000][0]==0,<<350>>} are not differential equations or initial conditions in the dependent variables {TemporaryVariable$10000,TemporaryVariable$100000,TemporaryVariable$100001,TemporaryVariable$100002,TemporaryVariable$100003,TemporaryVariable$100004,TemporaryVariable$100005,TemporaryVariable$100006,TemporaryVariable$100007,TemporaryVariable$100008,TemporaryVariable$100009,TemporaryVariable$10001,TemporaryVariable$100010,TemporaryVariable$100011,TemporaryVariable$100012,TemporaryVariable$100013,<<20>>,TemporaryVariable$100032,TemporaryVariable$100033,TemporaryVariable$100034,TemporaryVariable$100035,TemporaryVariable$100036,TemporaryVariable$100037,TemporaryVariable$100038,TemporaryVariable$100039,TemporaryVariable$10004,TemporaryVariable$100040,TemporaryVariable$100041,TemporaryVariable$100042,TemporaryVariable$100043,TemporaryVariable$100044,<<119550>>}.
```

Answer (score 3):

`pdetoode` and `pdetoae` can deal with multidimensional PDE of course, actually I've solved multidimensional problem with them in several posts, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160105/1871) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134336/1871). To discretize the toy example in your question, you just need to:

```
eqnstest = D[T[x, y, t], y] == 0;
domain@x = {0, 1};
domain@y = {0, 2};
points@x = points@y = 5;
grid@x = Array[# &, points@x, domain@x];
grid@y = Array[# &, points@y, domain@y];
differenceorder=2;

Tpdetood = pdetoode[T[x, y, t], t, {grid@x, grid@y}, differenceorder];
eqnstest // Tpdetood
```

Notice definition of `grid` and `Tpdetood` can be shorten to:

```
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, y};
Tpdetood = pdetoode[T[x, y, t], t, grid /@ {x, y}, differenceorder];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77994/discussion-on-answer-by-xzczd-using-a-custom-method-to-discretize-functions-with).

Comment: @xzczd Seeing what you are talking about in the chat room, you can communicate immediately with other people in English without using translation software. You are wonderful.