# boundary conditions involving time derivative

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

Can we solve the following PDE by Mathematica,

[image]

where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Gamma =\partial \Omega$ is the boundary of $\Omega$, $\partial_\nu$ is the normal derivative, and $\nu$ is the outer unit vector.

First I tried to solve the equation by Matlab, but the tools (`pdepe`, pde toolbox.. etc) not include dynamic boundary conditions $(2)$.

I tried the `NDSolve` with mathematica, but this not work for me:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}], u[0, x] == 1, 
Derivative[1, 0][u][t, 0] == Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0],
Derivative[1, 0][u][t, 1] == -Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 1]}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

It generate the following error:

`NDSolve::bdord: Boundary condition -(u^(0,1))[t,0]+(u^(1,0))[t,0] should have derivatives of order lower than the differential order of the partial differential equation.`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, what issues did you encounter? It would make it much easier for people to answer your question if you provided the mathematica code you have so that we do not have to type it.

Comment: @S.Cho Where did this problem come from?

Comment: This is a heat equation with dynamic boundary conditions which involves time derivative on the boundary, Yes I tried many tools in Matlab as in Mathematica (NDSolve...) but all the known methods don't work for this type of boundary conditions.

Comment: @user21 I edited my first post.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144881/1871

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me to understand many new things to simplify the problem. It still a smal problem with NDSolve as follows  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndRR0.jpg

Comment: I think this clarify the first one https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjSbC.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can build a converging process.

```
U[0][x_] := 1; t0 = 1/50;
Do[U[t] = 
   NDSolveValue[{(u[x] - U[t - t0][x])/t0 == 
      D[u[x], x, x], (u[0] - U[t - t0][0])/t0 == 
      u'[0], (u[1] - U[t - t0][1])/t0 ==- u'[1]}, u, {x, 0, 1}];, {t, 
  t0, 10, t0}]
lst = Table[{t, x, U[t][x]}, {t, 0, 10, t0}, {x, 0, 1, .02}];
{ListPointPlot3D[lst, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "u"}, PlotRange -> All],
  Plot[U[10][x], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thank you Sir. Interesting idea ! It seems to be similar to MethodOfLines which fix time variable and discretize with respect to the space variable and then solving the resulting ODEs. Is that true ? Is this Process well-known in the litterature (how to justify that It always converges, rate of convergence..etc). Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: 1.Your 2nd b.c. is different from OP's. 2. For the b.c. you've chosen, your solution is not reliable, it's easy to verify the correct solution is $u(t,x)=1$.

Comment: @S.Cho The method is called explicit Euler.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! I updated the message.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It seems to be the same first code. It gives the first Plot and not the updated one.

Comment: It works with t_0=1/5.

Comment: @S.Cho It is necessary to compare the two methods on non-trivial initial data.

Comment: Yes, I do that right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `Timing` your methode last 1.45313 and xzczd's method last 0.015625 If I'm not wrong.

Comment: @S.Cho Time is lost on building `ListPointPlot3D[]`

Comment: I tested without Plotting.

Comment: I have not optimized the code. Just showed how it works.

Comment: Okey. How we can optimize it ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's not hard to notice the solution for your toy example is

$$u(t,x)=1$$

```
With[{u = u[t, x]},
  {eq, ic, bc} =
   {D[u, t] == D[u, x, x],
    u == 1 /. t -> 0,
    {D[u, t] == D[u, x] /. x -> 0, D[u, t] == -D[u, x] /. x -> 1}}];

test = u -> (1 &);

{eq, ic, bc} /. test
(* {True, True, {True, True}} *)
```

Anyway, it's enough for illustrating a solution so I won't change the example. Here I'd like to show a solution by discretizing the PDE in $x$ direction ourselves. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) to facilitate the generation of ODE system:

```
domain = {0, 1};
difforder = 4;
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, grid, difforder];
removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = removeredundant@ptoofunc@eq;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
tend = 10;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}];
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid]

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, ##}] & @@ domain
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you Sir. Very interesting !. It seems to work in a good way. I need some time to better understand the `pdetoode` function. Is It works when the domain is a Disk for example ? Thanks again.

Comment: @S.Cho It can handle any regular domain (rectangular, disk, etc.).

Comment: @xzczd Is it possible to expand the use of the function  `pdetoode` to solve 3D and 4D?

Comment: @AlexTrounev `pdetoode` /`pdetoae` can handle high dimensional PDEs ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134336/1871) is a post using `pdetoode` to solve a 2+1D problem), but the troublesome parts are: 1. Problem that is spatially 3D or higher is not that easy to solve for any numeric solver in most cases, AFAIK; 2. Additionally, since `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` generates symbolic ODE/AE for every grid points, the memory requirement of `pdetoode`/`pdetoae` is rather demanding when the problem is spatially 3D or higher, which is usually beyond the reach of PC.

Comment: @xzczd I tried with centered initial condition u[0,x]==Exp[-(x-0.5)^2] but the plotting not working. What's the problem ?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. I reproduced the example. I will try to apply `pdetoode` for other problems.

Comment: @S.Cho Try adding `PlotRange->All` to `Plot3D`.

Comment: @xzczd I tried to Solve the 2D case by `pdetoode` (the same equation in Disk[] using polar cordinate, since the derivative on the boundary are not easy with Cartesian cordinate) but It doesn't work. Should I change the pdetoode to fix this ?

Comment: In fact I tried this one
 
`domain = Disk[];
difforder = 4;
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,please find it \
in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, r, z], t, grid, difforder];
removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = removeredundant@ptoofunc@eq;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc;
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
tend = 10;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}];
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid]

Plot3D[sol[t, r, z], {t, 0, tend}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> All] & @@ domain`

Comment: with this `With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, {eq, ic, 
    bc} = {D[u, t] == D[u, r, r] + (1/r) D[u, r] + (1/r^2) D[u, z, z],
     u == 1 /. 
     t -> 0, {(D[u, t] == 
        D[u, r, r] + (1 + 1/r) D[u, r] + (1/r^2) D[u, z, z]) /. 
      r -> 1}}];

test = u -> (1 &);

{eq, ic, bc} /. test`

Comment: Sorry in this case the domain with r and z is a Rectangle. but still this problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjvm0.jpg

Comment: @S.Cho You're using `pdetoode` blindly, notice it's just a auxiliary tool for the implementation of method of lines, so you need to know the basic of method of lines. Also, though you don't need to read through the source code of `pdetoode`, you must understand what those codes outside of `pdetoode` are doing, including but not limited to `Array`, `#&`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I know the method of lines in 1-D, here is 2-D problem, and in fact I'm new to using mathematica. I tried to Solve the problem basing on the previous example but I don't get where is the problem. For example what are the points deleted here `xdomain = ydomain = {-1, 1};
del = Delete[#, {{1}, {2}, {-2}, {-1}}] &;`

Comment: @S.Cho Notice `pdetoode` generates ODEs for every grid points when discretizing PDE, while we also have equations generated from b.c., so we need to remove some of the equations to _make room_ for the b.c.. If you still don't get it, try a coarse grid and observe the output carefully.

Comment: The problem still in how to choose these equations to be removed. First I thought that it is related to the boundary of the domain, but It seems not.

Comment: @S.Cho You may want to read the comments under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174775/1871).

Comment: Still misundesrtanding the problem, may be because I'm new to Mathematica and also my english is not good enough to understand better. I think a simple example in 2-D should help. I posted my problem here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190754/ndsolve-error-in-2-d-heat-equation. Thank you for every things.

Comment: @S.Cho One thing I forgot to say, "I know the method of lines in 1-D, here is 2-D problem"，then I'm afraid you don't know method of lines. Method of lines for 1D and 2D have no essential difference. Once again, `pdetoode` is just a auxiliary tool for the implementation of method of lines, you need to know the basic of this method. To test if you've understood the basic: do you know how to implement the method without `pdetoode`?

Comment: What I know is : In the method of lines we descretize the equation and BCs w.r.t space variables and solving the resulting ODEs, I implemented it in 1-D. It is the same for 2-D case, but still some troubles in removing some equations to make room for bc equations as you said. If you recommend any reference to better understanding MOL It would be nice. Thank you again.

Comment: @S.Cho Then how will you implement method of lines **without** `pdetoode`? Notice I need to remove equations because `pdetoode` has been designed to generate equations for every grid point (it uses one-sided formula at and near the boundary, if you're not familiar with one-sided formula, start from page 6 of [this book](https://disciplinas.stoa.usp.br/pluginfile.php/41896/mod_resource/content/1/LeVeque%20Finite%20Diff.pdf). This book is also a good reference for FDM, which is closely related to method of lines).