# Trouble with dependent variables in NDSolve while modelling transparent boundary conditions on a quantum graph with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, graphs-and-networks, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I am trying to create a model of plane wave's propagation on a quantum graph(metric graph with a differential operator, Shrodinger operator in my case, along the edges and continuity condition at the vertices) with given multi-bond transparency boundary conditions at a point 0:
[image: My graph's image]
[image: Shrodinger equation; V = 0 in my case]

Given initial and boundary conditions look like this:
[image: Conditions]

I'm trying to solve it with Mathematica:

```
initialConditions = {
  u11[0, x] == Sin[Pi*(x + 10)/10]^2,
  u12[0, x] == 0,
  u11[t, -10] == 0,
  u11[t, 0] == 0,
  u12[t, 0] == 0,
  u[t, x] == u11[t, x] + u12[t, x]
  }
boundaryConditions = {
  -I*(3/2)*((D[ u12[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) - (D[u11[t, x], x] /. 
         x -> 0)) + ((D[ u12[t, x], t, x] /. 
        x -> 0) - (D[u11[t, x], t, x] /. x -> 0)) + 
    3*I*((D[ u12[t, x], t] /. x -> 0) - (D[u11[t, x], t] /. 
         x -> 0)) == 0,
  I*D[u11[t, x], t] + (1/2)*D[u11[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0,
  I*D[u12[t, x], t] + (1/2)*D[u12[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0
  }
uix = NDSolveValue[{initialConditions, boundaryConditions}, 
  u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -10, 0}]
```

But I keep getting this error:
[image: Error]

If someone has already experienced such troubles in similar problems, I would highly appreciate any help.

Thanks for your attention.

**Update**

1. All functions should be zero at x = ±10.
2. 11 is defined at [-10, 0], 12 at [0, 10].
3. I've split one equation for  to two for 11 and 12, because otherwise, Mathematica raised an error "system is underdetermined"
4. I've put {x, -10, 0} because otherwise, I'm getting an error, which states, that 0 is not a boundary, so BC can not be defined. So I decided to split the problem into two calculations(maybe in the wrong way).

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, a few questions: **1.** What's the b.c. at $x=\pm 10$? **2.** Are $\psi_{12}$ and $\psi_{11}$ both defined on $[-10,10]$? **3.** In your code you write `I*D[u11[t, x], t] + (1/2)*D[u11[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0,
  I*D[u12[t, x], t] + (1/2)*D[u12[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0`, which is inconsistent with the one in the picture, which one is correct? **4.** In the code you write `{x, -10, 0}`, which is again inconsistent with the picture, which one is correct?

Comment: Hello, @xzczd, thanks for the answer. **1.** All functions should be zero at x =  ±10. **2.** 11 is defined at [-10, 0], 12 at [0, 10]. **3.** I've split one equation for  to two for 11 and 12, because otherwise, Mathematica raised an error "system is underdetermined"**4.** I've put `{x, -10, 0}` because otherwise, I'm getting an error, which states, that 0 is not a boundary, so BC can not be defined. So I decided to split the problem into two calculations(maybe in the wrong way).

Comment: So you're solving a problem similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218983/1871), in the sense that there's a boundary condition inside the domain?

Comment: @xzczd yes, I think in that way it is kind of similar. But the main problem with the "dependent variables in boundary conditions" remains. Maybe you can give me a piece of advice on how to reformulate my boundary condition at 0 to solve it with Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, this problem is somewhat similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/218983/1871), and harder, because the b.c. at $x=0$ involves first order derivative of $t$, which will lead to `bdord` warning in this case. ([Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190360/1871) is an example about dealing with `bdord` warning. )

So, again, let's discretize the system in $x$ direction all by ourselves. I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task.

```
{lb = -10, mb = 0, rb = 10, tmax = 100};

With[{u = u[t, x]}, eq = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic = {u == Sin[Pi (x + 10)/10]^2, u == 0} /. t -> 0;
  {bcl, bcm, bcr} = {u == 0 /. x -> lb, 
                     -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
                     u == 0 /. x -> rb}];

points = 25; {gridl, gridr} = Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr} = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, #, difforder] & /@ {gridl, gridr};

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
{odel, oder} = del@#@eq & /@ {ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr};
{odeicl, odeicr} = MapThread[#@#2 &, {{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr}, ic}];
{odebcl, odebcr} = MapThread[#@#2 &, {{ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr}, {bcl, bcr}}];
odebcm = Equal @@ (#@bcm & /@ {ptoofuncl, ptoofuncr});

odebc = {odebcm, With[{sf = 1}, diffbc[t, sf]@{odebcl, odebcr}]};

sollst = NDSolveValue[{odel, odeicl, oder, Rest@odeicr, odebc}, {u /@ gridl, 
     u /@ gridr}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming

{soll, solr} = MapThread[rebuild, {sollst, {gridl, gridr}}];

sol = {t, x} \[Function] Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr[t, x]];

DensityPlot[sol[t, x] // #, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, lb, rb}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    Exclusions -> None, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"] & /@ {Re, Im} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try to apply this approach to a three-bonded star graph by myself.