# Modelling transparent boundary conditions on a three-bonded quantum graph

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, graphs-and-networks, boundary-conditions

I've created two issue last year, but unfortunately was able to return to this problem only now.

This question is a continue to [this issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219372/trouble-with-dependent-variables-in-ndsolve-while-modelling-transparent-boundary?rq=1).

Essentially I am now trying to apply a solution from the question above to three-bonded star graph (I am trying to apply method, suggested by @xzczd in [another issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221998/modelling-transparent-boundary-conditions-on-a-quantum-graph-with-mathematica-nd)).

System of equations:
[image]

I was able to create such a code (link to [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190360/boundary-conditions-involving-time-derivative)):

```
{lb = -20, mb = 0, rb = 20, tmax = 24.3};
func1[x_] = 2/(9*Pi)*Exp[-((x + 10)^2/9) + I*(x + 10)];
With[{u = u1[t, x]}, eq1 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic1 = {u == func1[x], u == 0} /. t -> 0;
  {bcl1, bcm1, 
    bcr1} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb}];

With[{u = u2[t, x]}, eq2 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic2 = {u == 0, u == 0} /. t -> 0;
  {bcl2, bcm2, 
    bcr2} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb}];

With[{u = u3[t, x]}, eq3 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic3 = {u == 0, u == 0} /. t -> 0;
  {bcl3, bcm3, 
    bcr3} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb}];
(*Creating two grids, each corresponds to an edge of the graph
*)
points = 100; {gridl, gridr} = 
 Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};

difforder = 2;
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[u1[t, x], t, gridl, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[u2[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];
ptoofunc3 = pdetoode[u3[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];


del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;


ode1 = del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2;
ode3 = del@ptoofunc3@eq3;


odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
odeic3 = ptoofunc3@ic3;


odebc1 = ptoofunc1@bcl1;
odebc2 = ptoofunc2@bcr2;
odebc3 = ptoofunc3@bcr3;


odebcm1 = ptoofunc1@bcm1 == ptoofunc2@bcm2;
odebcm2 = ptoofunc1@bcm1 == ptoofunc3@bcm3;
odebcm3 = ptoofunc2@bcm2 == ptoofunc3@bcm3;

odebc = {odebcm1, odebcm2, odebcm3, 
   With[{sf = 1}, 
    Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebc1, odebc2, odebc3}, {2}]]};
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, odeic1, Rest@odeic2, 
     Rest@odeic3, odebc}, {u1 /@ gridl, u2 /@ gridr, u3 /@ gridr}, {t,
      0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming;
```

But I keep getting error:
[image]

I would be grateful for any suggestions considering my problem. thanks for your attention

**UPDATE**

According to @xzczd suggestion, I've tried to correct a few conditions:

- initial conditions are now just `ic1 = u == func1[x] /. t -> 0;`, `ic2 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;`, `ic3 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;`
- $\psi_{11}(−0)=\psi_{12}(+0)=\psi_{13}(+0)$ condition is now implemented as `odebcmzero =  ptoofunc1@bczero1 == ptoofunc2@bczero2 == ptoofunc3@bczero3;`
- only `odebcm1` now present in NDSolve

The code looks like this:

```
{lb = -20, mb = 0, rb = 20, tmax = 24.3};
func1[x_] = 2/(9*Pi)*Exp[-((x + 10)^2/9) + I*(x + 10)];
With[{u = u1[t, x]}, eq1 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic1 = u == func1[x] /. t -> 0;
  {bcl1, bcm1, bcr1, 
    bczero1} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u2[t, x]}, eq2 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic2 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl2, bcm2, bcr2, 
    bczero2} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u3[t, x]}, eq3 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic3 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl3, bcm3, bcr3, 
    bczero3} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];
(*Creating two grids, each corresponds to an edge of the graph
*)
points = 50; {gridl, gridr} = 
 Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};

difforder = 2;
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[u1[t, x], t, gridl, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[u2[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];
ptoofunc3 = pdetoode[u3[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];


del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;


ode1 = del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2;
ode3 = del@ptoofunc3@eq3;


odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
odeic3 = ptoofunc3@ic3;


odebc1 = ptoofunc1@bcl1;
odebc2 = ptoofunc2@bcr2;
odebc3 = ptoofunc3@bcr3;


odebcm1 = ptoofunc1@bcm1 == ptoofunc2@bcm2;
(*odebcm2 = ptoofunc1@bcm1==ptoofunc3@bcm3;
odebcm3 = ptoofunc2@bcm2==ptoofunc3@bcm3;*)

odebcmzero = 
  ptoofunc1@bczero1 == ptoofunc2@bczero2 == ptoofunc3@bczero3;

odebc = {odebcm1, odebcmzero, 
   With[{sf = 1}, 
    Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebc1, odebc2, odebc3}, {2}]]};
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, odeic1, Rest@odeic2, 
     Rest@odeic3, odebc}, {u1 /@ gridl, u2 /@ gridr, u3 /@ gridr}, {t,
      0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming;
```

I'm still getting error:
[image]

but at least it outputs an interpolating functions, which is kind of progress.

**FINAL SOLUTION**
Thanks to @xzczd's invaluable assistance, I was able to fix existing problems:

- removed `Rest@` for initial conditions
- aded `With[{sf = 1}, Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, odebcmzero, {2}]` trick

So, fully-working code with the demonstration looks like this (you also should add [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190360/boundary-conditions-involving-time-derivative) function at the beginning of the file):

```
{lb = -20, mb = 0, rb = 20, tmax = 24.3};
func1[x_] = 2/(9*Pi)*Exp[-((x + 10)^2/9) + I*(x + 10)];
With[{u = u1[t, x]}, eq1 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic1 = u == func1[x] /. t -> 0;
  {bcl1, bcm1, bcr1, 
    bczero1} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u2[t, x]}, eq2 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic2 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl2, bcm2, bcr2, 
    bczero2} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u3[t, x]}, eq3 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic3 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl3, bcm3, bcr3, 
    bczero3} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];
(*Creating two grids, each corresponds to an edge of the graph
*)
points = 100; {gridl, gridr} = 
 Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};

difforder = 2;
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[u1[t, x], t, gridl, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[u2[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];
ptoofunc3 = pdetoode[u3[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];


del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;


ode1 = del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2;
ode3 = del@ptoofunc3@eq3;


odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
odeic3 = ptoofunc3@ic3;


odebc1 = ptoofunc1@bcl1;
odebc2 = ptoofunc2@bcr2;
odebc3 = ptoofunc3@bcr3;


odebcm1 = ptoofunc1@bcm1 == ptoofunc2@bcm2;
(*odebcm2 = ptoofunc1@bcm1==ptoofunc3@bcm3;
odebcm3 = ptoofunc2@bcm2==ptoofunc3@bcm3;*)

odebcmzero = 
  ptoofunc1@bczero1 == ptoofunc2@bczero2 == ptoofunc3@bczero3;

odebc = {odebcm1, 
   With[{sf = 1}, Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebcmzero}, {2}]], 
   With[{sf = 1}, 
    Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebc1, odebc2, odebc3}, {2}]]};
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, odeic1, odeic2, odeic3, 
     odebc}, {u1 /@ gridl, u2 /@ gridr, u3 /@ gridr}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming;
{soll, solr1, solr2} = 
  MapThread[rebuild, {sollst[[2]], {gridl, gridr, gridr}}];
sol1 = {t, x} \[Function] 
   Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr1[t, x]];
sol2 = {t, x} \[Function] 
   Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr2[t, x]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Abs[sol1[t, x]]^2, {x, lb, rb}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, 
    "|\[Psi]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \(2\)]\), First-second bond \
propagation"}, PlotRange -> All], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, tmax, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[Abs[sol2[t, x]]^2, {x, lb, rb}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, 
    "|\[Psi]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \(2\)]\), First-third bond \
propagation"}, PlotRange -> All], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, tmax, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Several problems I can spot at the moment: 1. Definitions of `ic1`, `ic2`, `ic3` are incorrect, because we've introduced `u1`, `u2` and `u3`, the code should be modified accordingly. 2. Similarly, we need to code the condition $\psi_{11}(-0)=\psi_{12}(+0)=\psi_{13}(+0)$ explicitly. 3. The most serious problem: something is wrong with the conditions at the node. It's not too hard to notice four conditions i.e. $\psi_{11}(-0)=\psi_{12}(+0)=\psi_{13}(+0)$ and one of `odebcm1`, `odebcm2`, `odebcm3` already determines a solution.

Comment: @xzczd, thank you for your immensely useful tips, I've tried to make corrections you suggested (considering initial conditions - in my mind it should be just one equation for each function, because at the beginning of the whole process wave is present only on the first bond for `u1`, and not present on two other bonds for `u2` and `u3`). It seems to push the problem a bit further, because it outputs interpolating function, but the issue is still present.

Comment: 1. `Rest` before `odeic1` and `odeic2` should be removed now. 2. We need the `With[{sf = 1}, Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, …, {2}]` trick for `odebcmzero`.

Comment: @xzczd yes, that absolutely nails it! Greatest thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**
Thanks to [@xzczd's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd) invaluable assistance, I was able to fix existing problems:

- removed `Rest@` for initial conditions
- aded `With[{sf = 1}, Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, odebcmzero, {2}]` trick

So, fully-working code with the demonstration looks like this (you also should add [pdetoode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190360/boundary-conditions-involving-time-derivative) function at the beginning of the file):

```
{lb = -20, mb = 0, rb = 20, tmax = 24.3};
func1[x_] = 2/(9*Pi)*Exp[-((x + 10)^2/9) + I*(x + 10)];
With[{u = u1[t, x]}, eq1 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic1 = u == func1[x] /. t -> 0;
  {bcl1, bcm1, bcr1, 
    bczero1} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u2[t, x]}, eq2 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic2 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl2, bcm2, bcr2, 
    bczero2} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];

With[{u = u3[t, x]}, eq3 = I D[u, t] + 1/2 D[u, {x, 2}] == 0;
  ic3 = u == 0 /. t -> 0;
  {bcl3, bcm3, bcr3, 
    bczero3} = {u == 0 /. 
     x -> lb, -3 I/2 D[u, x] + D[u, t, x] + 3 I D[u, t] /. x -> mb, 
    u == 0 /. x -> rb, u /. x -> mb}];
(*Creating two grids, each corresponds to an edge of the graph
*)
points = 100; {gridl, gridr} = 
 Array[# &, points, #] & /@ {{lb, mb}, {mb, rb}};

difforder = 2;
ptoofunc1 = pdetoode[u1[t, x], t, gridl, difforder];
ptoofunc2 = pdetoode[u2[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];
ptoofunc3 = pdetoode[u3[t, x], t, gridr, difforder];


del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;


ode1 = del@ptoofunc1@eq1;
ode2 = del@ptoofunc2@eq2;
ode3 = del@ptoofunc3@eq3;


odeic1 = ptoofunc1@ic1;
odeic2 = ptoofunc2@ic2;
odeic3 = ptoofunc3@ic3;


odebc1 = ptoofunc1@bcl1;
odebc2 = ptoofunc2@bcr2;
odebc3 = ptoofunc3@bcr3;


odebcm1 = ptoofunc1@bcm1 == ptoofunc2@bcm2;
(*odebcm2 = ptoofunc1@bcm1==ptoofunc3@bcm3;
odebcm3 = ptoofunc2@bcm2==ptoofunc3@bcm3;*)

odebcmzero = 
  ptoofunc1@bczero1 == ptoofunc2@bczero2 == ptoofunc3@bczero3;

odebc = {odebcm1, 
   With[{sf = 1}, Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebcmzero}, {2}]], 
   With[{sf = 1}, 
    Map[sf # + D[#, t] &, {odebc1, odebc2, odebc3}, {2}]]};
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, odeic1, odeic2, odeic3, 
     odebc}, {u1 /@ gridl, u2 /@ gridr, u3 /@ gridr}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity] // AbsoluteTiming;
{soll, solr1, solr2} = 
  MapThread[rebuild, {sollst[[2]], {gridl, gridr, gridr}}];
sol1 = {t, x} \[Function] 
   Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr1[t, x]];
sol2 = {t, x} \[Function] 
   Piecewise[{{soll[t, x], x < mb}}, solr2[t, x]];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Abs[sol1[t, x]]^2, {x, lb, rb}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, 
    "|\[Psi]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \(2\)]\), First-second bond \
propagation"}, PlotRange -> All], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, tmax, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[Abs[sol2[t, x]]^2, {x, lb, rb}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, 
    "|\[Psi]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(|\), \(2\)]\), First-third bond \
propagation"}, PlotRange -> All], {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, tmax, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```