# Heat equation with nonlinear boundary condition involving time-derivative

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-difference-method

The governing equation is shown as follows:

[image]

I first try to employ the `NDSolve`, but it seems that *Mathematica* can not handle the fourth boundary condition.

Therefore, I rewrite the code with finite difference method, but still have problem

```
Mr = 100; Mz = 10; Lr = 10; Lz = 1;
γ = 0.01;
α = 1;
κ = 1;
dr = Lr/Mr;
dz = Lz/dz;
dt = 0.1;
r[i_] := i*dr;
z[j_] := j*dz;


(*i.c.*)
u[i_, j_, 0] := 0;
(*b.c.*)
u[1, j_, k_] := u[2, j, k] + 2;
u[Mr, j_, k_] := u[Mr - 1, j, k];
u[i_, 1, k_] := u[i, 2, k];
u[i_, Mz, k_] := 
  If[k == 1, 0, 
   1/dz^2 (dt dz γ u[i, -1 + Mz, -1 + k] + 
      dt α γ u[i, -1 + Mz, -1 + k]^2 + 
      dz^2 u[i, Mz, -1 + k] - dt dz γ u[i, Mz, -1 + k] - 
      2 dt α γ u[i, -1 + Mz, -1 + k] u[i, Mz, -1 + k] + 
      dt α γ u[i, Mz, -1 + k]^2)];

u[i_, j_, k_] := 
  u[i, j, k] = 
   1/(dr^2 dz^2 i) (dt dz^2 i u[-1 + i, j, -1 + k] + 
      dr^2 dt i u[i, -1 + j, -1 + k] - dt dz^2 u[i, j, -1 + k] - 
      2 dr^2 dt i u[i, j, -1 + k] + dr^2 dz^2 i u[i, j, -1 + k] - 
      2 dt dz^2 i u[i, j, -1 + k] + dr^2 dt i u[i, 1 + j, -1 + k] + 
      dt dz^2 u[1 + i, j, -1 + k] + dt dz^2 i u[1 + i, j, -1 + k]);

u[1, Mz, 1]
```

However,  I receive the following error message

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

The problem may be induced by the imposion of nonlinear and  time-derivative and nonlinear boundary condition. Any idea about how to solve my problem? This boundary condition has bothered me for long time.

---

I re code the provided code as follows

```
Clear[fdd, pdetoode, tooderule]
fdd[{}, grid_, value_, order_] := value;
fdd[a__] := NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative@a;

pdetoode[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoode[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], 
   rest];
pdetoode[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoode[Alternatives[func][var], rest];
pdetoode[rest__, grid_?VectorQ, o_Integer] := 
  pdetoode[rest, {grid}, o];

pdetoode[func_[var__], time_, {grid : {__} ..}, o_Integer] := 
  With[{pos = Position[{var}, time][[1, 1]]}, 
   With[{bound = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ {grid}, 
     pat = Repeated[_, {pos - 1}], 
     spacevar = Alternatives @@ Delete[{var}, pos]}, 
    With[{coordtoindex = 
       Function[coord, 
        MapThread[
         Piecewise[{{1, # === #2[[1]]}, {-1, # === #2[[-1]]}}, 
           All] &, {coord, bound}]]}, 
     tooderule@
      Flatten@{((u : func) | 
            Derivative[dx1 : pat, dt_, dx2___][(u : func)])[x1 : pat, 
          t_, x2___] :> (Sow@coordtoindex@{x1, x2};

          fdd[{dx1, dx2}, {grid}, 
           Outer[Derivative[dt][u@##]@t &, grid], 
           "DifferenceOrder" -> o]), 
        inde : spacevar :> 
         With[{i = Position[spacevar, inde][[1, 1]]}, 
          Outer[Slot@i &, grid]]}]]];

tooderule[rule_][pde_List] := tooderule[rule] /@ pde;
tooderule[rule_]@Equal[a_, b_] := 
  Equal[tooderule[rule][a - b], 0] //. 
   eqn : HoldPattern@Equal[_, _] :> Thread@eqn;
tooderule[rule_][expr_] := #[[Sequence @@ #2[[1, 1]]]] & @@ 
  Reap[expr /. rule]

Clear@pdetoae;
pdetoae[funcvalue_List, rest__] := 
  pdetoae[(Alternatives @@ Head /@ funcvalue) @@ funcvalue[[1]], rest];
pdetoae[{func__}[var__], rest__] := 
  pdetoae[Alternatives[func][var], rest];

pdetoae[func_[var__], rest__] := 
  Module[{t}, 
   Function[
      pde, #[pde /. {Derivative[d__][u : func][inde__] :> 
           Derivative[d, 0][u][inde, t], (u : func)[inde__] :> 
           u[inde, t]}] /. (u : func)[i__][t] :> u[i]] &@
    pdetoode[func[var, t], t, rest]];
\[Gamma] = 100;
\[Alpha] = 0;
\[Kappa] = 1;
R = 10;
Z = 1;
eps = 10^-1;
tend = 1000;

eq = With[{u = u[r, Sqrt[\[Kappa]] z, t]}, 
   Laplacian[u, {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] == D[u, t] /. 
    Sqrt[\[Kappa]] z -> z];

ic = u[r, z, 0] == 0;
bc = With[{u = u[r, z, t]}, {D[u, r] == -2/r /. r -> eps, 
   u == 0 /. r -> R, D[u, z] == 0 /. z -> 0, D[u, z] == 0 /. z -> Z}]

domain@r = {eps, R};
domain@z = {0, Z};
points@r = 50;
points@z = 50;
difforder = 2;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {r, z};

(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,please find it \
in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[r, z, t], t, grid /@ {r, z}, difforder];

delbothside = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ode = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@eq;

odeic = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = MapAt[delbothside, ptoofunc@bc, {{1}, {2}}];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
   Outer[u, grid@r, grid@z] // Flatten, {t, 0, tend}];

sol = ListInterpolation[
      Partition[Developer`ToPackedArray@#["ValuesOnGrid"] & /@ #, 
       points@z], {grid@r, grid@z, #[[1]]["Coordinates"][[1]]}] &@
    sollst; // AbsoluteTiming

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[sol[r, z, t], {r, eps, R}, {z, 0, Z}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 10}], {t, 0, tend}]
```

The equation indicate that the upper and under boundary conditions are subjected to no-flow condition. And it can easily be solved and obtain an analytical solution.

To compare the analytical solution (or semi-analytical), the solution can be expressed as

```
Vi[n_, i_] := 
 Vi[n, i] = (-1)^(i + n/2) Sum[ 
     k^(n/2) (2 k)! /( (n/2 - k)! k! (k - 1)! (i - k)! (2 k - 
            i)! ), { k, Floor[ (i + 1)/2 ], Min[ i, n/2] } ] // N; 
Stehfest[F_, s_, t_, n_: 16] :=
 If[n > 16, Message[Stehfest::optimalterms, n];
        If[ OddQ[n], Message[Stehfest::odd, n];
                "Enter an even number of terms",
                If[n > 32, Message[Stehfest::terms, n];
                    " Try a smaller value for n. Maximum allowable n is 32 ",
                    Log[2]/t Sum[ Vi[n, i]*F /. s -> i Log[2]/t , {i, 1, n} ] ]],
        If[ OddQ[n], Message[Stehfest::odd, n];
                "Enter an even number of terms", 
    If[n > 32, Message[Stehfest::terms, n];
                    " Try a smaller value for n. Maximum allowable n is 32.",
                    Log[2]/t Sum[ 
       Vi[n, i]*F /. s -> i Log[2]/t , {i, 1, n} ] ]]]  // N; 
s0[r_, z_, t_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Re[Stehfest[(
     2 E^(-((Sqrt[a^2 + p] z)/
       Sqrt[\[Kappa]])) (-E^((Sqrt[a^2 + p]/Sqrt[\[Kappa]]))
           p \[Gamma] - 
        E^((Sqrt[a^2 + p] (1 + 2 z))/Sqrt[\[Kappa]]) p \[Gamma] + 
        E^((Sqrt[a^2 + p] z)/
         Sqrt[\[Kappa]]) (p \[Gamma] - Sqrt[a^2 + p] Sqrt[\[Kappa]]) +
         E^((Sqrt[a^2 + p] (2 + z))/
         Sqrt[\[Kappa]]) (p \[Gamma] + 
           Sqrt[a^2 + p] Sqrt[\[Kappa]])))/(
     p (a^2 + 
        p) ((1 + E^((2 Sqrt[a^2 + p])/
           Sqrt[\[Kappa]])) p \[Gamma] + (-1 + E^((2 Sqrt[a^2 + p])/
           Sqrt[\[Kappa]])) Sqrt[a^2 + p] Sqrt[\[Kappa]])), p, t, 6]]*
   BesselJ[0, a (r)]*a, {a, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {BesselJ}}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 40];
```

with `\[Gamma] = 0;`
I however compare the numerical results and analytical one. It seems that the the numerical solution obtain a wrong result. The code and the plot of comparison are shown as follows

```
\[Gamma] = 0; TT1 = Table[{t, s0[0.9, 0.5, t]}, {t, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
TT2 = Table[{t, s0[0.9, 0.5, t]}, {t, 1, 10, 1}];
TT3 = Table[{t, s0[0.9, 0.5, t]}, {t, 10, 100, 10}];
TT4 = Table[{t, s0[0.9, 0.5, t]}, {t, 100, 1000, 100}];
C0 = Join[TT1, TT2, TT3, TT4];
TT1 = Table[{t, sol[1, 0.5, t]}, {t, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
TT2 = Table[{t, sol[1, 0.5, t]}, {t, 1, 10, 1}];
TT3 = Table[{t, sol[1, 0.5, t]}, {t, 10, 100, 10}];
TT4 = Table[{t, sol[1, 0.5, t]}, {t, 100, 1000, 100}];
Cn = Join[TT1, TT2, TT3, TT4];
```

[image]

The figure is u versus t and blue and yellow lines represent the value predicted by numerical and analytical solutions, respectively.
 I an trying to figure out what happen to the numerical method.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment below, please add a complete example for producing the graph.

Comment: @xzczd The full code is given.

Comment: The `γ` in 2 approaches have different definitions?

Comment: The same meaning. But I need to let it become zero to get the same solution form to compare to numerical result. Because the analytical solution is derived from the use of the nonlinear boundary condition and let gamma zero to reduce the upper boundary condition (i.e., the nonlinear boundary) to no-flow one.

Comment: In a word you deliberately make the 2 `γ` different, right? Then with `points@r = 170; points@z = 170; difforder = 4;` (you may also need to add `SolvedDelayed -> True` to `NDSolve`, this option is red, but don't worry), the numeric solution is very close to the semi-analytic one up to `t=50`. BTW the code for plotting can be simplified to `\[Gamma] = 0;
C0 = {#, s0[0.9, 0.5, #]} & /@ Exp@N@Range[-1, Round@Log@1000, 1/3];

ap = ListLogLinearPlot[C0];
np = LogLinearPlot[sol[1, 0.5, t], {t, 0.1, 1000}];
Show[ap, np, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Yes, they are different.  What is the SolvedDelayed function? Can it make the result more accuracy or faster? I cannot find the application or example for this function. Moreover, the simplified coed for plotting is so efficiency!

Comment: The Mathematica sent me the error message like "NDSolveValue::optx: Unknown option SolvedDelayed in NDSolveValue" as I make code look like this "sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, 
  Outer[u, grid@r, grid@z] // Flatten, {t, 0, tend}, 
  SolvedDelayed -> True]"

Comment: …I made a typo. It should be `SolveDelayed`. As to the reason about why I added it, check [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134669/1871)

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, I am puzzled why the greater time the more inaccurate for the result. The smaller MaxStepSize and the infinity of MaxStep seem not to improve the results

Comment: In most cases, it's just needless to touch `MaxStepSize` and `MaxStep`, because default step size control is quite robust. I strongly suspect the semi-analytic solution doesn't correctly describe the behavior of the model for large `t`, because the solution should tend to a steady state after a certain time, it's the property of solution of heat equation when there's Dirichlet boundary condition, as far as I know.

Comment: You are right. The behavior of u should achieve the steady state due to the Dirichlet condition at the right boundary condition. Sorry to forget to mention that the right boundary condition for semi-analytical solution is adopted infinite condition. Therefor, I chose a very large value of R. It can be found that the influence radius for both approach not exceed r = 5. I thick the chosen value r = 10 is acceptable for simulation. Maybe I need to check the other numerical Laplace inverse algorithm to validate.

Comment: Oh, the semi-analytic solution is based on numerical Laplace inversion? Then try [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/) and [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4738/).

Comment: Thank you! The semi-analytical solution is more efficiency than the analytical one if it is included the integral or infinite sum.

Comment: I'm afraid approximating the boundary condition at infinity with Dirichlet condition at `R=10` is improper for large `t`. Just compare the result above to e.g. `R=5; points@r=points@z=50`,  the influence radius is clearly expanding over time, unboundedly.

Comment: Do you mean I need to input larger value of R to simulate the infinite condition? Does it imply that I need to add more grid? If I apply points@r=points@z more than 80, the Mathematica would out of memory.

Comment: Yes, as long as you need such a large `t`. As to the memory issue, it's possible to reduce memory usage, but it's troublesome. The method in my current answer no longer applies. Low level implementation of discretization for the spatial dimension is needed, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120501/1871) is an example, and your case is even more cumbersome, because the boundary condition involves derivatives, so we need [one-sided difference formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134567/1871) for precise discretization of them.

Comment: Thank you for your time. BTW, why your code form do not look like I learn from the guide of Mathematica on line and book? How do you learn it?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) (BTW [here](http://www.mathcraft.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mathematica_%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%EF%BC%9A%E9%AB%98%E7%BA%A7%E5%AF%BC%E8%AE%BA)'s the unfinished Chinese edition of it) and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2dsyvptnxjd369/Wagner%20All%20Parts-RC.pdf) book?

Comment: It is awesome! The Chinese version would be helpful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`NDSolve` has trouble in handling the last b.c., so let's help it a bit by discretizing the PDE and corresponding i.c. and b.c. to a set of DAE.

First, interpreting your equation set to *Mathematica* code:

```
γ = 1/100;
α = 1;
κ = 1;
R = 10;
Z = 1;
eps = 10^-1;
tend = 1;

eq = With[{u = u[r, Sqrt[κ] z, t]}, 
   Laplacian[u, {r, th, z}, "Cylindrical"] == D[u, t] /. Sqrt[κ] z -> z];

ic = u[r, z, 0] == 0;
bc = With[{u = u[r, z, t]},
   {D[u, r] == -2/r /. r -> eps,
    u == 0 /. r -> R,
    D[u, z] == 0 /. z -> 0,
    -1/γ eq[[1]] == D[u, z] - α D[u, z]^2 /. z -> Z}]
```

Notice I've substitute the PDE to the last b.c., because it turns out that, `NDSolve` can't handle the original one very well even after discretization.

Then it's time for discretization, I'll use [`pdetoode`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the task:

```
domain@r = {eps, R};
domain@z = {0, Z};
points@r = 25;
points@z = 25;
difforder = 4;
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {r, z};

(* Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[r, z, t], t, grid /@ {r, z}, difforder];

delbothside = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ode = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@eq;

odeic = delbothside /@ delbothside@ptoofunc@ic;
odebc = MapAt[delbothside, ptoofunc@bc, {{1}, {2}}];

sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, Outer[u, grid@r, grid@z], {t, 0, tend}];
```

Finally, rebuild the solution from the discretized one and plot:

```
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid /@ {r, z}, -1]; // AbsoluteTiming

Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[r, z, t], {r, eps, R}, {z, 0, Z}, PlotRange -> {-1, 10}], 
           {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image]

Comment: What's the amazing work! thank you! I need time to understand your code.

Comment: (+1) BTW, I still didn't understand how you input that weird bc. It's (MMM) now zhk.

Comment: this bc represents the drainage from the top. Some one linearize the moving bc like this. However, i m trying to input the linearized one (i.e., alpha is equal to zero), the numerical results can not match the semi-analytical solution (the equations with alpha = 0 can be solved). It produce the negative values somewhere.

Comment: @zhk The left hand side (RHS) of the weird b.c. is $\partial{u}/\partial{t}$, which is the same as the RHS of the PDE, so I substitute the PDE to that b.c.. (Just evaluate `eq[[1]]` separately and see what will happen. )

Comment: @JOJO I believe you mean something like that mentioned in this post?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10055/1871

Comment: Yes, the numerical value diverges as time is large. Neglecting the nonlinear term (i.e., alpha=0) also occur the incorrect values implying that the nonlinear term is not the cause. I further replace eq[[1]] with eq[[2]] and the Mathematic shows the error like:Structural analysis indicates that 554 initial conditions are needed to fix the state of the system

Comment: @jojo You cannot simply replace `eq[[1]]` with `eq[[2]]`, because if you want to directly use the last b.c., the equations to be removed is different. If your problem is the same as that mentioned in the previous link, then as suggested in that post, make the grid denser i.e. try e.g. `points@r = 50; points@z = 50;`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to use the smaller grid as <pre>points@r = 50; points@z = 50. <code>. The 3D plot still show the strange graph as adopting <pre>tend= 20 <code>.

Comment: @jojo Which part is "strange"? I only get a result similar to what's shown in my answer.

Comment: Also, I would like to know why the finite-difference code I put above show the error like Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/Udaca) This figure show the value I chose to evaluate the numerical result.
And the strange result is shown as [link](http://imgur.com/a/Xe8Dc)
Comparing with the semi-analytical solution(blue line) demonstrate that  [link](http://imgur.com/a/XJgri).
The tend cannot be too large? How can I revise the time step? Thank you.

Comment: I found the error of Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded is induced by dz = Lz/dz.

Comment: @jojo The trouble maker is the necessarily small `eps` (The `R` is `10`, you choose `eps=10^-2` so `1000 eps == R`! Remember for numeric evaluation even a `eps` satisfying `10 eps==R` can be called as "much smaller than `R`".), I'm not completely sure about the reason, but using `eps = 10^-1` will resolve the problem. As to FDM, I just want to say FDM is more than "transform the differential equation into difference equation", there're too many possible issues in its implementation, not to mention you've coded it in a fallible way. Just check those posts tagged with [finite-difference-method].

Comment: It is really helpful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @xzczd Bother again. I'm trying to apply your code and reduce the last boundary condition to - D[u, z] == 0 /. z -> Z. But the numerical result still give the wrong value when I compare it with the analytical solution. I think the problem is not on the boundary condition but somewhere. I further adjusted the number of the step, step size, and accuracy. Also try difference method like MethodofLine. I cannot figure out why the numerical result get wrong even I apply it to the above-mentioned simpler condition.

Comment: @jojo Please show me a complete example illustrating your problem, you can add it to your question by clicking the [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/144881/edit) button.

Comment: @xzczd the example is demonstrated following the previous quation