# Slight change in boundary contains giving unexpected results

Tags: differential-equations

I cannot find out where the difference comes from.

First pde, `solBM30`, has variable boundary condition which I evaluate at a certain point. The second pde, `solBM32` is identical, except it has a fixed boundary condition which is then evaluated at the same point. The results should be equal right?

```
σ = 0.; 
K = 110; 
S = 20; 
E = 10; 
θ = 0.000023637253287033743; 
κ = 0.008622227075117428; 
cr = -0.00024031738413887727; 
small = 0.01; 

solBM30 = 
  NDSolve[
    {D[F[r0, t], {t}] == (-(θ - κ r0)) D[F[r0, t], {r0}], F[r0, K] == 10000 r0}, 
    F, {t, 0, K}, {r0, cr - small, cr + small}]; 

solBM32 = 
  NDSolve[
    {D[W[r0, t], {t}] == (-(θ - κ r0)) D[W[r0, t], {r0}], W[r0, K] == 10000 cr}, 
    W, {t, 0, K}, {r0, cr - small, cr + small}];

(*Plot[slice[r0],{r0,rd,ru}]*)
F[cr, 0] /. solBM30
W[cr, 0] /. solBM32
```

Edit: Added the 'full' PDE. Now I get another error.

```
solBM1 = NDSolve[{0 == 
    0.5*σ^2*D[V[r0, t], {r0}, {r0}] + (θ - κr0)*
      D[V[r0, t], {r0}] - r0*V[r0, t] + D[V[r0, t], {t}], 
   V[r0, K] == 
    1, (D[V[r0, t], {t}] + θ*D[V[r0, t], {r0}] /. r0 -> 0) == 
    0}, {V}, 
     {t, 0, K}, {r0, cr - small, cr + small}]
```

Edit2:

```
r1 = -0.000240317
M = 111;
si = 0.000212693;
b = 0.00862223;
a = 0.0000236373;
R = 1/10;

eq = 0 == 0.5*si^2*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + (a - b*x)*D[u[t, x], x] - 
    x* u[t, x] - D[u[t, x], t];
ic = u[0, x] == 1 ;
bc = {(-D[u[t, x], {t}] + a*D[u[t, x], {x}] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
  u[t, R] == Exp[-R*t]}
domain = {0, R};
difforder = 4;
points = 25;
grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
(*Definition of pdetoode isn't included in this post,please find it \
in the link above.*)
ptoofunc = pdetoode[u[t, x], t, grid, difforder];
removeredundant = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
ode = removeredundant@ptoofunc@eq;
odebc = ptoofunc@bc
odeic = ptoofunc@ic;
tend = M;
sollst = NDSolveValue[{ode, odeic, odebc}, u /@ grid, {t, 0, tend}];
sol = rebuild[sollst, grid];

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, ##}] & @@ domain
```

Edit3 (Beware I corrected a mistake in the first b.c in edit2 ):

```
vas[t_, r0_] = a/b + (r0 - a/b)*Exp[-b*t];
B[t_, T_] := (1 - E^(-b (T - t)))/b
A[T_, t_] := (a/b - si^2/(2 b^2)) (B[t, T] - (T - t)) - (
  si^2 B[t, T]^2)/(4 b)
Z1[t_, T_] := E^(A[T, t] - 0*B[t, T])
Z2[t_, T_] := E^(A[T, t] - vas[t, 0] B[t, T])
Plot[{sol[M - t, 0], Z1[t, M], Z2[t, M]}, {t, 0, M}]
```

Comment: Do not use `E, K` - Built-in Symbols.

Comment: Here is the hyperbolic equation, the slope of the characteristic changes sign on the left and right border. Therefore, it is necessary to put two boundary conditions.

Comment: It's necessary to provide b.c. in `r0` direction when solving the problem numerically.  Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28744/5331

Comment: Many thanks! This means that a boundary condition must be defined as a function of t? Can I choose any r0 to define this function ? Are there any other ways to find a b.c?

Comment: I believe this article gives me guidance: [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.1149.pdf)

Comment: I edited the post to reflect updates based on the help you gave and the article. This is the pde I am aiming at but with variable boundary condition such as the stripped down version I first gave. But first Id like the b.c to work.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment, or I won't get the reminder. Then, 1. The full PDE is completely different from the simplified one, they belong to 2 different categories. 2. One more b.c. approximating b.c. at infinity is necessary. 3. `NDSolve` cannot handle the b.c. at `r0==0`, so we need to discretize the equation all by ourselves, [`pdetoode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) can be used for the task.

Comment: @xzczd. Does that mean that if 2. is solved, no discretization is needed (seems like a lengthy task)?

Comment: @xzczd , pdetoode seems promising. Do you have an exmaple similar to the above equation?

Comment: No, issue 2 and issue 3 are separate i.e. we need to add the missing boundary and discretize the equation ourselves. We already have several questions similar to yours in this site, for example [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190360/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144881/1871), you may have a look.

Comment: @xzczd, please see edit2. I am having trouble using pdetoode. I am new to MMA so my problems may be trivial. Could you also explain the difforder of x (in the first example it is 4, so I recon it is 4 in my application - but I am unsure here). Otherwise the first example you gave seems to match my application of pdetoode.

Comment: 1. Use `R=1/10` to define `R`, `MachinePrecision` number can cause trouble because `pdetoode` currently uses `===` to check if an equation is on the boundary. (Well, perhaps I should re-design this part. ) 2. `domain` should be `domain={0,R}`. 3. `difforder` is short for differen**ce** order i.e. it's the order of the differen**ce** formula used for discretization.

Comment: I've updated `pdetoode`, now it can handle definition like `R=0.1` properly.

Comment: @xzczd. Thanks alot! I am sorry if this seems like a moving target. My problem is now to match the analytical solution. In Edit3 A and B are the solutions to the Riccatti equations. When r0>0 r0 can be a constant (Z1) and the analytical and numerical yields the same. But when r <= 0 the correct solution is only achieved with r as a function (Z2). Now the funny part. The numerical and the anaytical (Z1) are identical and seems to commit the same mistake. Z2 is what you expect - can be shown with a simple ODE. It would be interesting to see if you see what is going on here. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Do you mean you've deduced 2 analytic solutions `Z1` and `Z2`, but `Z1` is wrong and the numeric solution is the same as `Z1`? If so, the only thing I know at this point is, I believe the numeric solution is reliable enough, if it doesn't match the analytic solution, you should check whether same problem is solved or not.

Comment: @xzczd. I see. Solution Z2 is correct, The numerical solution is not. By accident I achieve the wrong numerical solution by using a constant r=r(0) in B (some references suggested this). I was hoping this could be a clue as to why the numerical solution is off. The problem I believe has nothing to do with Pdetoode. Normal NDSolve also fives this result. Pdetoode provided nice help in supplying more b.c's, but to no avail.  Let me know if I can provide you with more information.

Comment: @xzczd. There is one more b.c. to try: D[u[t, x], {t}] /. x -> 0==0. Pdetoode then yields an error. Could you please have a look?Thank you !

Comment: It should be `(D[u[t, x], {t}] /. x -> 0)==0` or `D[u[t, x], {t}] ==0/. x -> 0`.

Comment: Thanks @xzczd. Still I dont get it work I am afraid.