# Numerically solve large ODE system

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica. I am tasked with using `NDSolve` to numerically solve ~10^6 non-linear, coupled ODEs. However, I am only able to solve up to 100 on my computer. My professor says I should be able to do at least 1000. I'm guessing my code is not efficient, but I'm not sure what else to do. Any ideas? I have attached my code:

```
latSize = 20;
μ = 3;

Do[Do[
  Subscript[kx, i, j] = i;
  Subscript[ky, i, j] = j;

  Subscript[x0, i, j] = 
   Re[1/2*Sqrt[1 - ((2*μ - (i^2 + j^2))/(2*(i^2 + j^2)))^2] E^(-I*
      ArcTan[j/i])];
  Subscript[y0, i, 
   j] = -1*Im[
     1/2*Sqrt[1 - ((2*μ - (i^2 + j^2))/(2*(i^2 + j^2)))^2] E^(-I*
       ArcTan[j/i])];
  Subscript[z0, i, j] = 1/2*((2*μ - (i^2 + j^2))/(2*(i^2 + j^2)));
  , {j, 1, latSize, 1}]
 , {i, 1, latSize, 1}]

(* Set up delta *)
G = 5;
SuperPlus[Δ1] = -G*
   Sum[Sum[Subscript[kx, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] + 
      Subscript[ky, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t], {j, 1, latSize, 
      1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];
SuperMinus[Δ1] = -G*
   Sum[Sum[Subscript[kx, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] - 
      Subscript[ky, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t], {j, 1, latSize, 
      1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];
SuperPlus[Δ2] = 
  G*Sum[Sum[
     Subscript[ky, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] - 
      Subscript[kx, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t], {j, 1, latSize, 
      1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];
SuperMinus[Δ2] = -G*
   Sum[Sum[Subscript[ky, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] + 
      Subscript[kx, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t], {j, 1, latSize, 
      1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];

(* Set up B *)
Do[Do[
   Subscript[B1, i, j] = 
    2*Subscript[kx, i, 
      j] (SuperPlus[Δ1] + 
        SuperMinus[Δ1]) + 
     2*Subscript[ky, i, 
      j] (SuperMinus[Δ2] - SuperPlus[Δ2]);
   Subscript[B2, i, j] = 
    2*Subscript[kx, i, 
      j] (SuperPlus[Δ2] + 
        SuperMinus[Δ2]) + 
     2*Subscript[ky, i, 
      j] (SuperPlus[Δ1] - SuperMinus[Δ1]);
   Subscript[B3, i, j] = Subscript[kx, i, j]^2 + Subscript[ky, i, j]^2;
   , {j, 1, latSize, 1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];

(* Set up DE *)
Do[Do[
   Subscript[x, i, j]'[t] == 
    Subscript[B2, i, j]*Subscript[z, i, j][t] - 
     Subscript[B3, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t];
   Subscript[y, i, j]'[t] == 
    Subscript[B3, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] - 
     Subscript[B1, i, j]*Subscript[z, i, j][t];
   Subscript[z, i, j]'[t] == 
    Subscript[B1, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t] - 
     Subscript[B2, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t];
   , {j, 1, 2, 1}], {i, 1, latSize, 1}];

s = NDSolve[
   Flatten[Table[{Subscript[x, i, j]'[t] == 
       Subscript[B2, i, j]*Subscript[z, i, j][t] - 
        Subscript[B3, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t], 
      Subscript[y, i, j]'[t] == 
       Subscript[B3, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t] - 
        Subscript[B1, i, j]*Subscript[z, i, j][t], 
      Subscript[z, i, j]'[t] == 
       Subscript[B1, i, j]*Subscript[y, i, j][t] - 
        Subscript[B2, i, j]*Subscript[x, i, j][t], 
      Subscript[x, i, j][0] == Subscript[x0, i, j], 
      Subscript[y, i, j][0] == Subscript[y0, i, j], 
      Subscript[z, i, j][0] == Subscript[z0, i, j]}, {i, 1, 
      latSize}, {j, 1, latSize}]], 
   Flatten[Table[{Subscript[x, i, j], Subscript[y, i, j], Subscript[z,
       i, j]}, {i, 1, latSize}, {j, 1, latSize}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> Solve}];
```

In vector form the equation would be:
$\frac{d \vec{r_i}}{dt} = \vec{B_i}\times \vec{r_i}$
Where $\vec{B_i} = \vec{B_i}(\vec{r_1},\vec{r_2},...)$

So if we define $\vec{B} = (B1,B2,B3)$, where the subscript i has been omitted. The B components are of the form:
$B_1 = 2*k_x(\Delta1^+ + \Delta1^-) + 2*k_y(\Delta2^- - \Delta2^+)$
Where the deltas have the form: $\Delta1^+ = -G*\sum_{i} k_x*x+k_y*y$

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I've replaced the image with the code in text.

Comment: The last `Do` loop is redundant. Then, related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131411/1871 . I think the best solution is to rewrite the system in vector form, but it's tedious to figure out the vector form of the system from your code. Do you already have the vector form of the system at hand? Or at least the system expressed with traditional math notation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The system is basically:
    dr_i/dt = B_i x r_i

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment, or I won't get the reminder. Can you add the specific formula in $\LaTeX$ form to your question?

Comment: @xzczd Oh, thanks haha. I've added the equations as you requested.

Comment: @olabaz Does $\times$ stand for cross product? How about those coefficients? Do you have their vector forms at hand?

Comment: Yes, the $\times$ is a cross product. What do you mean by coefficients? Everything is encoded in the B's. I will add them to the post explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I mean those $B$s. Without the original form of them, it's hard to check whether they're correct or not. (They're highly suspicious, I should say. In your code, $\text{$\Delta $1}^-+\text{$\Delta $1}^+$ and $\text{$\Delta $2}^--\text{$\Delta $2}^+$ and $\text{$\Delta $2}^-+\text{$\Delta $2}^+$ are actually the same! )

Comment: @xzczd Ah, indeed that's true! But I still need them separated for calculations in the future. Should I screenshot my code, so it's easier to read?

Comment: Screenshot won't make the code any easier to read. If you really want to make the question more readable, show us a minimal working example, or at least add as much background information as possible and, as mentioned above, show us the original form of the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since OP doesn't give the background information of the equation system, I can just make some limited optimization. Anyway, it's clear that OP's problem is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131411/1871): large  symbolic ODE system is burdensome, not only for the generation and storage of the system, but also for pre-process of `NDSolve`. (In some cases it even triggers bug, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134669/1871) for an example. ) So, let's rewrite the system in vectorized form:

```
b1 = 2 kx (delta[1, plus] + delta[1, minus]) + 2 ky (delta[2, minus] - delta[2, plus]);
b2 = 2 kx (delta[2, minus] + delta[2, plus]) + 2 ky (delta[1, plus] - delta[1, minus]);
b3 = kx^2 + ky^2;

cross = {b1, b2, b3}\[Cross]{x, y, z};

deltarule = {delta[1, plus] :> -G Total@Flatten@(kx x + ky y), 
             delta[1, minus] :> -G Total@Flatten@(kx x - ky y), 
             delta[2, plus] :> G Total@Flatten@(ky x - kx y), 
             delta[2, minus] :> -G Total@Flatten@(ky x + kx y)};

latSize = 20;
μ = 3; G = 5;
xy0 = Table[
   1./2 Sqrt[1 - ((2 μ - (i^2 + j^2))/(2 (i^2 + j^2)))^2] E^(-I ArcTan[j/i]), {i, 
    latSize}, {j, latSize}];
x0 = Re@xy0; y0 = -Im@xy0;
z0 = Table[(2. μ - (i^2 + j^2))/(2 (2 (i^2 + j^2))), {i, latSize}, {j, latSize}];
krule = {kxlst -> Table[i, {i, latSize}, {j, latSize}], 
         kylst -> Table[j, {i, latSize}, {j, latSize}]};

rhsfunc = (Hold@
         Compile[{{r, _Real, 3}}, 
          With[{kx = kxlst, ky = kylst}, Module[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = r; #]], 
          CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
          RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False] /. deltarule /. krule // 
      ReleaseHold) &@cross;
tend = 10^-4;
sol = NDSolveValue[{r'[t] == rhsfunc@r@t, r[0] == {x0, y0, z0}}, 
    r, {t, 0, tend}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.288241, Null} *)

test = Table[sol[t], {t, 0, tend, tend/100}];
ListLinePlot[test[[All, 1, 1, 1]], DataRange -> {0, tend}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I have been going through the code and I was wondering if you could clarify a few things:

Could you explain what rhsfunc is doing? I have no experience with compiled functions and how they interact with "with", "module", and "&@cross".

Also, NDSolveValue gives me the value of r(t) from 0 to tend and then it is plotted? How can I choose which kx,ky I want to plot?

Comment: `rhsfunc[r[t]]` (in my code, I wrote `rhsfunc@r@t`, they're equivalent) is $\vec{B_i}\times \vec{r_i}$. Well, I admit compiling is advanced technique, to fully understand the `rhsfunc`, consider starting from the following uncompiled version: `Clear@rhsfunc; core = (Hold@
        Function[r, 
         With[{kx = kxlst, ky = kylst}, Module[{x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = r; #]]] /. 
       deltarule /. krule // ReleaseHold) &@cross;
rhsfunc[r_?ArrayQ] := core[r]`. …

Comment: …You may also want to read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871). `sol[(*time*)]` will evaluate to a 3 dimensional list whose size is `3×latSize×latSize`. (Try `sol[(*time*)]//Dimensions`. ) To choose the specific $k_x$, $k_y$, you just need `sol[(*time*)][[All, (*index of kx*), (*index of ky*)]]`.

Comment: Oooh, I see this is very cool. How would I plot `delta[1, plus]` as a function of time? Is there any easy way?

Comment: Ah, the delta should account for all of them for example, in a 2x2 lattice:
$delta[1, plus] :> -G [(1) x_1 + (1)*y_1 +(2)x_2 + (1)*y_2 + (1)*x_3 + (2)*y_3 +(2)x_4 + (2)*y_4]$

Comment: Then `Plot[delta[1, 
   plus] /. (deltarule /. Thread[{x, y} -> sol[t][[1 ;; 2]]] /. {kx -> kxlst, 
      ky -> kylst} /. krule), {t, 0, tend}]`